# Which came first - the Matrix entry name convention or the Programming for loop variable name convention?

Tags: terminology, math-history

So, conventionally, entries in a matrix are referred to as $A_{ij}$ - $i$th row, $j$th column.

For historical reasons (least partially due to Cobol naming restrictions based on what I've read, but I could be wrong), variable names for `for` loops will also be `i` and, for nested loops, `j`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
      //..
     }
 }
```

Is this resemblance purely coincidental, or was one "borrowed" from the other? If one was "borrowed," which one came first?

Comment: Mostly, it comes from the fact that $i$ comes before $j$ in the alphabet and $i$ is the first letter of the word index.

Comment: To emphasize the subscript notation, in every example and every lecture I ever do on or related to the topic, I always use R before C.  You will never hear me say "rows and columns" in the other order if I can help it (*unless it is to emphasize a particular property or is otherwise necessary*).  So, the players in the game are Rob and Charles, or it is the Rumrunners and the Coastgard, or Robbers and Cops.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How does the fact that $i$ comes before $j$ explain why $A_{ij}$ isn't the entry in the $i^{\text{th}}$ column, $j^{\text{th}}$ row?

Comment: Matrices were around long before Cobol (or even Fortran).